# Stable test data for a SAP function module?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, abap

We extract data from SAP IS-U to create [RDI](https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=%22SAPscript%20Raw%20Data%20Interface%22&language=en-US&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_750) which gets used to create PDF via [caps](https://www.tbz-pariv.de/produkte/caps/ubersicht).

We want to create automated integration tests.

The function modules we want to test are not trivial. For example creating an annual invoice reads a lot of data in a lot of tables. We need to be sure that all this data does not change. Otherwise the tests will fail.

Therefore we need stable test data inside SAP. Unfortunately we don't have this at the moment.

The sap development systems get accessed by many people. And from time to time these systems get updated with data from the production system.

How to get stable test data for SAP IS-U?

My personal opinion: the provider of the custom solution/component (in this case the  IS-U) should provide stable test data. Otherwise every development team starts to create its own stable test data again and again.

Comment: You wrote "unit tests". For unit tests you should mock your DAO interfaces (well, if you have any) and provide your test data there, otherwise if you use the data from the database (which is often client dependent) then your unit tests are everything but unit test, they are integration tests. You cannot base your post assertions on no stable preconditions.

Comment: @Jagger please don't take the term "unit test" to literal. I wrote several thousand unittests in Python. And this is the first time that I want to write a test in ABAP. I just want to be sure that the abap code does what it should do. The abap code reads a lot of different tables. I guess according to your comment this is "integration testing", or am I wrong?

Comment: If you read directly from the database with SELECT queries for example and you have not hidden your data access behind interfaces then you tightly coupled your business logic with data access and yes in fact you are doing an integration test between your server and your database in such a case.

Comment: @Jagger Question1: is it discouraged to use SELECT in ABAP? I thought it is very common to do this.

Comment: Do not get me wrong. It is not discouraged to use a SELECT. It is _where_ you should use it. You should hide such data acesses behind an interface, to be able to mock it for your unit tests which should be done in isolation.

Comment: @Jagger I updated the question: We want to create automated integration tests.

Comment: If you do not want to rewrite your code, then request for a separate SAP client in your test system where the data will not be changed by the updates from the production system.

Comment: @Jagger In my experience the designated "DAO interfaces" in IS-U are mostly a set of plain old function modules in which few lines of SAP standard code `SELECT` rows from the database and maybe does some minimal post processing or filtering. Is there an **elegant** way to mock the output of these function modules for testing purposes or do you have to add an extra layer in between SAP standard code and the code under test?

Comment: @konstantin Exactly I was talking about this special layer, one have to build by himself in order to achieve the testability of the code. The SAP has delivered by today no standard way to mock function module calls.

Comment: 1st Idea. You could ask to build your stable (or a new one) dataset on production (ensuring it has no expiry date), so that copy of production will rewrite this same dataset. 2nd Idea At us, RDI are plaintext files that we archive for few days. Depending on the test goals, you can keep this file to provide it to "caps" as SAP would (at us it is making it available in the right folder). 3rd Idea, make the test unit start sooner in the "business workflow" to make it build the dataset you need. 4th Idea Maybe the dataset can be saved in a transport order, to import after each production copy.

Comment: 5th Idea, you can store the data you need in another place you can maintain yourself : a dabase table, a flat file...

Comment: assuming the tests are for the caps components and not for the data selection in sap.

Comment: From what I understood there is no separation between data selection and caps layer, so it is a small integration test and not unit test. Well, maybe there is but it is tightly coupled to these other components.

Comment: @Jagger I removed the term "unit" from the text of the question. I want an automated test. Up to now I think the only way to get this working is to fill tables with fixed data.

Answer (score 2):

From our discussion under the question I could say that the simplest solution would be to request for a separate client in your test system where the data could not be updated by the periodical copy from the production. This would ensure that your data remain stable for your post conditions in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ABAP TestDouble Framework](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5371047f1273405bb46725a417f95433/Cloud/en-US/804c251e9c19426cadd1395978d3f17b.html) available since ABAP 740 SP09. It was introduced exactly for this, for being independent on the productive database state and without changing production code.

The approach used to achieve this is called mocked DAO and described in the blogs below

[image]

The mocking is achieved by creation of test double object and configuring method output values through **cl_abap_testdouble** class methods

```
cl_abap_testdouble=>create( )
cl_abap_testdouble=>configure_call( )
```

Consider this whole blog series that describes DAO concept and TestDouble:

- [Mocking DAOs with ABAP Test Double Framework](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/25/mocking-daos-with-abap-test-double-framework/)
- [ABAP Test Double Framework – An Introduction](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/01/05/abap-test-double-framework-an-introduction/)
- [ABAP Unit Tests without database dependency – DAO concept](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/03/21/abap-unit-tests-without-database-dependency-dao-concept/)